# how to pass one component service response to other component in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 4,
getting response from server in one component and I want this response object in other component how to access

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selected;
  skipCount: number = 0;
  errorMessage: string;
  searchedResults: any;

  searchObj: Object = {
    skipCount: this.skipCount
  };

  onChange(newVlaue){
    console.log(newVlaue);
    this.selected = newVlaue;
  }

  constructor(
    private searchService: searchService,
    private router: Router) {}

  searchall() {
    console.log(this.searchObj);

    var searchData = this.searchObj;
    console.log(searchData);

    this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(this.searchObj)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.searchedResults = data;
          console.log(this.searchedResults);
          this.router.navigate(['/searchdetails/'])
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

I want searchedResults variable result in other component like search details
how to get this.

Thanks!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: seems like you want to pass the searchedResults to your searchdetails component. Show your SearchDetailsComponent and routing

Comment: @brijmcq yes how can i achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the search results in your searService and get it back from there. For this just add the searchResults property in your service and update it with the current search results. It would look something like the following:

```
export class SearchService {
  public searchResults;

  ... 
}
```

and whenever you want to update the search results you would do: 
```

```
this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(this.searchObj).subscribe(data=>{
  this.searchedResults = data;
  this.searchService.searchResults = data; 
},error=>this.errorMessage= <any>error);
```

you can also overwrite your search function that you update the searchResults property automatically when finding results in your service.

and in the other component you can just user the property from the service

```
this.searchedResults = this.searchService.searchResults;
```

If you want that the component updates automatically with the new date you either have to bind the userService directly to the input or add a listener for the data change.

Comment: can you bit elaborate.how do i use that searchResults(which is in search.service.ts) in other component

Comment: check the edit. You can directly bind the searchResults property toy our @Input field of components - easiest way, as it will automatically update components when data changes and you don't need to add a listener.

Comment: when i navigating to search detail page the previous view also displaying.i.e two views displaying

Comment: please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110810/passing-one-component-data-to-other-component?noredirect=1#comment79185291_46110810